# Getting Person having interests in more number of subjects - Sql Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

Sorry for the subject as it is not very definientia. I have 2 tables, one stores Person Data and one stores Subject data along with the person interested in. Two tables looks like below

**Person**

```
Id  Name
1   Imad
2   Sumeet
3   Suresh
4   Navin
```

**Subjects**

```
Id  PId Subject
1   1   DC
2   1   DS
3   3   DS
4   4   CA
```

PId is a Persons' Id

I need to get all students who are interested in max number of subjects, e.g Imad here.

Here is my query

```
With c as
(
    select Pid, count(Id) as 'Total' from subjects group by Pid
)
select Pid into #Temp from c where Total = (Select Max(Total) from c)
select * from Person where Id in (Select Pid from #Temp)
```

It gives me desired output but whenever this type question is asked in interview, I never get good response from interviewer as they always expect better solution. I am not confident on my SQL skills that's why I think there must be more efficient solution hence I posted it here.
Thanks

Comment: Study up on your SQL.  You don't need a temporary table for a query such as this.

Comment: I agree, but don't know other way.

Comment: Tid ? subject ? those are non-existing objects

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Simply order the data and get top most one record with ties(this means if some students have equal counts they both will come in result):

```
select top 1 with ties p.Id, p.Name
from Subjects s
join Person p on s.PId = p.Id
group by p.Id, p.Name, 
order by count(*) desc
```

Comment: At least 2008 R2 does support.

Comment: I have checked, even 2005 supports. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189463(v=sql.90).aspx

Comment: Right, just one join and here is the solution :)

Answer (score 1):

You can try this :

```
;With c as
(
    select Pid, count(Id) as 'Total' from subject group by Pid
)

select * from Person join c on c.Pid=Person.Id where c.total>1
```

Comment: Replaced your where with mine total = (select  max(Total) from c) and it looks better :)

Comment: @ImadoddinIbnAlauddin If so , you asked the wrong question. you asked  : _interests in more number of subjects_  .not : _interests in max number of subjects_  :-)

Answer (score 0):

Try to this

```
select * from person
    where id in(
    Select b.pid
    from subject b 
    group by b.pid
    having count(b.pid)>1
    )
```

Comment: You want to students who are interested in most subjects. so when you group by to count return value of which pid to most subject

Comment: I am sorry for not making proper sentence. I have updated my quetion, Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

```
    declare @t table (ID int,name varchar(10))
    insert into @t (ID,name)values (1,'imad'),(2,'sumeet'),(3,'suresh'),(4,'navin')
    declare @tt table (Id int,Pid int,Subject varchar(10))
    insert into @tt (Id,Pid,subject)values (1,1,'DC'),(2,1,'DS'),(3,3,'DS'),(4,4,'CA')

 select p.ID,P.name,ttt.Subject from (Select P.ID,P.name,P.Cnt from (
select t.ID,t.name,COUNT((t.ID))Cnt from @t t
 INNER JOIN 
@tt tt ON t.ID = tt.Pid 
GROUP BY t.ID,t.name)P
GROUP BY P.Cnt,P.ID,p.name
HAVING(cnt) > 1)P
INNER JOIN @tt ttt ON Ttt.Pid = P.ID
```

Answer (score 0):

The current solutions with `TOP` are MS SQL Server specific. Following solution is based on Standard SQL's Windowed Aggregate Functions, which most DBMSes support:

```
select Pid, Total
from 
 (
   select Pid, count(Id) as Total
      ,rank() over (order by count(Id) desc) as rn
   from subjects group by Pid
 ) as dt
where rn = 1
```